# Problem printing from cups

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, printing, cups-lpd

I have connected printer Brother HL-L2310D to server on Debian.
I can print all from server i.e. test page from cups.
Printer is shared in network and on PC with Windows 10 there sending job to server and printer print it.

Problem is on Kubuntu: it sends print job to cups server, printer is trying to print (flashing led and relay make sound) but after few seconds it's stopped and says "printed ok".
I downloaded newest driver for this printer and configured it as http://100.100.0.70:631/printers/Brother_HL-L2310D_series.

When i connect printer directly to Kubuntu it works fine and printing everything.

Comment: Look at log files in `/var/log/cups/` on Debian server. Maybe they'll shed some light on the issue.

Comment: in access_log all success-ok, error_log empty, page_log only jobs from win10 pc.